# Tightening a newel post bolt in a tight space

Tags: tools, stairs, post

I have a couple of newel posts on my stairs that have gotten wobbly over the years. In an attempt to tighten them up, I removed the plugs at the bottom of the posts to access the bolts holding them to the floor in the hopes that I could tighten up the nuts. It's got a 1 inch nut, so I bought a 1 inch wrench. But, I can't get the wrench in there to go around the bolt. There isn't enough space for either the open end or the box end.

Someone obviously managed to tighten that bolt when the post was installed, but I don't see how there would be room in there, and my searching hasn't been able to find a way to tighten that up. Any ideas on what I could do?

[image: Post with bolt]

[image: Post with bolt]

Comment: That nut takes a 1" wrench? That implies that the bolt is something like 5/8". You sure about that?

Comment: Not 100% sure since I haven't been able to get a wrench on it and measuring in that small space is challenging. I did have a 3/4" wrench I got in there, but it was too small.

Comment: Heavy 5/8" nuts have a flat to flat dimension of 1-1/16". That could be the reason you can't get a wrench on it. (Your 1" wrench would work for an ordinary 5/8" nut.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the tool you're probably needing is what's called a ratcheting wrench.  They're made for tight spaces and if you get one with a high number of ratcheting teeth (giving you lots of room for tight spaces and small amounts of rotation each turn), you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Some box wrenches are lower profile or skinnier than others, might be worth looking around. The rise angle will also help to get the arm closer to the center of the whole where you have more rotation.

Another thing you can try is hammering a large flat blade screw driver against the side of the nut to rotate it.

You may find even if you manage to tighten it that it still rocks. The post may need to be anchored in a different direction to secure it, such as to the stair riser.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bolt. There's a head. You torque the head, and if the nut rotates, eventually it will align nicely to give your open ended wrench a bite. Use the open ended wrench as a backup wrench.

On another question, somebody torqued a couple of screws to wedge between the washer and the post's wood to tighten something similar to this. You might try that pattern first if the bolt head is buried behind drywall or something.

After you tighten the bolt, expect it to get loose again. Wood creeps (it's more appropriate in this case to say that it "relaxes"). You might check out Figure 5-22 from the FPL's [Wood Handbook](https://www.fpl.fs.usda.gov/documnts/fplgtr/fpl_gtr190.pdf). If you could continuously maintain the clamping pressure at, say, 500 psi for 100 to 200 days straight, then you would finally begin to approach the flat asymptote from that creep curve, and the bolt would begin to maintain pressure without attention.

[image: Figure 5-22]

Even after effectively reaching the asymptotic limit from the graph, variation in moisture content can swoop in and relieve some of the pressure.

I think that urethane springs like [these](https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/32000283) are potentially a reasonably priced solution to the creep problem that could maintain relatively stable clamping force. The idea is still half-baked, though.

Comment: For clarity—you're suggesting opening up the ceiling (or whatever there is) below the bottom of the post, and turning the bolt *head,* correct?

Comment: @Huesmann, exactly.